# Python Dictionary: Accessing the previous value using current/present key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to be able to use a 'present' key and generate it's previous key's values. Here is an example with a starting point from which I am unable to move further:

```
#d= {}

d = {
 {'Neighbour_values': [{3: [2, 89.5488]}, {3: [4, 23.0558]}, {4: [2, 89.5488]}, {5: [2, 89.5488]}, {5: [3, 122.153]}, {5: [4, 22.9872]}, {6: [2, 89.5488]}, {6: [4, 22.9872]}, {7: [2, 89.5488]}, {7: [4, 22.9872]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}, {8: [4, 22.9872]}]}, 
 {'Neighbour_values': [{3: [4, 23.0558]}, {4: [1, 19.9884]}, {4: [3, 122.153]}, {5: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [3, 122.153]}, {7: [1, 19.9884]}, {8: [1, 19.9884]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}]}, 
 {'Neighbour_values': [{3: [2, 89.5488]}, {3: [4, 23.0558]}, {3: [6, 20.4196]}, {4: [1, 19.9884]}, {4: [2, 89.5488]}, {5: [1, 19.9884]}, {5: [4, 22.9872]}, {6: [2, 89.5488]}, {6: [4, 22.9872]}, {7: [2, 89.5488]}, {7: [4, 22.9872]}, {8: [2, 89.5488]}]}, 
 {'Neighbour_values': [{3: [1, 122.153]}, {3: [3, 71.1785]}, {3: [6, 20.4196]}, {4: [6, 20.4196]}, {5: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [3, 122.153]}, {6: [6, 20.4196]}, {7: [1, 19.9884]}, {7: [6, 19.9002]}, {8: [1, 19.9884]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}]}, 
 {'Neighbour_values': [{3: [4, 23.0558]}, {4: [4, 23.0362]}, {6: [3, 122.153]}, {6: [4, 22.9872]}, {7: [4, 22.9872]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}, {8: [4, 22.9872]}]}
    }

#print '\n'
#print(d)

for value in range(3,9):
    print '--- value ---'

    if value == 4:
        print value of 'Neighbour_values' in key 3 i.e 89.5488 and in next line 23.0558 (but do not print 2, 4)

        #and continue with the other keys in the dictionary i.e "for 2, 3, 4, and 6"

    next if value == 4+2:
        continue the above logic by printing value of 'Neighbour_values' in key 5 (again, only the float values and not the integers)
```

Of course a little bit of Pseudo code is written in the code as I do not know what to do further.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)
(Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-Bit VM and Python 2.7)

**UPDATE**

Edited the dictionary to be more precise as to what I want for in the solution.
Hope this makes the question more clear.

Comment: Dictionaries, especially in Python 2, are unordered. There is nothing like a previous item.

Comment: But your `d` is actually a list, not a dictionary. You are overwriting the initial dictionary.

Comment: You've got a rather complex data structure there old chap. Looks a like a list of tuples where the values are a dictionary with values of a list of dictionaries with value of a list of 2 numbers. May I suggest you simplify your data structure somewhat. Also I'm pretty sure that you don't need to do what your question subject says that you want to do i.e. accessing a previous value using a present key.

Comment: Can you clean up your data?  All the nesting is a mess in its current format. Also, you initiate `d` as a `dict` but then redefine it as a `list` of...`tuples`?

It seems as though you have a list of tuples of `(key, dict)`, and the dicts are really just `{'Neighbour_values': [list of dicts of {key: list}]}`. If the first value in your outermost tuple is just the order, you can get that by storing your data in a list, which you are doing anyway. Then 'Neighbor_values' is redundant, so you can remove that `dict` layer. Once you get to the actual values, you can organize those better.

Comment: Because the neighbor values seem consistent (i.e. `[4, 23.0558] and [2, 89.5448]`), I think *those* are what you want a `dict` for, like: `{1: 122.153, 2: 89.5488, 3: 71.1785...}`. Then for each item in your list, store a list of which items are neighbors, so instead of `[{3: [1, 122.153]}, {3: [3, 71.1785]}, {3: [6, 20.4196]},` you have `{3: [1,3,6]` where the items in the list can get their values from your previously defined `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
print('\n'.join([str(l[value-1][1]) for e in d for l in e[1]['Neighbour_values'] if value-1 in l]))
```

**output**

```
89.5488
23.0558
23.0558
89.5488
23.0558
20.4196
122.153
71.1785
20.4196
23.0558
89.5488
19.9884
122.153
19.9884
89.5488
20.4196
23.0362
89.5488
122.153
22.9872
19.9884
19.9884
22.9872
19.9884
89.5488
22.9872
19.9884
122.153
89.5488
22.9872
19.9884
122.153
20.4196
122.153
22.9872
89.5488
22.9872
19.9884
89.5488
22.9872
19.9884
19.9002
22.9872
```

**Explanation**

```
print('\n'.join(                    #Separate each element by \n
[                                   #Start List comprehension
str(l[value-1][1])                  #select item 1 from [2, 89.5488]
for e in d                          #for each main tuple of (1, {'Neighbour_values':...
for l in e[1]['Neighbour_values']   #iterate over dictionary like {3: [2, 89.5488]}
if value-1 in l                     #select only if key of value-1 is there
]
))
```

As your keys in this case are int, am not sure if you need to use OrderedDict. But if you are comfortable with your data structure for whatever reason, I'm just posting this as a way to wade through it to achieve your output.

**UPDATED for additional detail in OP**

Your latest `d` is not a proper dictionary as it doesn't have keys, so I changed it to a dictionary with keys. If you want the code to work properly please use the `d` as initialized below:

```
d = {
 1:{'Neighbour_values': [{3: [2, 89.5488]}, {3: [4, 23.0558]}, {4: [2, 89.5488]}, {5: [2, 89.5488]}, {5: [3, 122.153]}, {5: [4, 22.9872]}, {6: [2, 89.5488]}, {6: [4, 22.9872]}, {7: [2, 89.5488]}, {7: [4, 22.9872]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}, {8: [4, 22.9872]}]}, 
 2:{'Neighbour_values': [{3: [4, 23.0558]}, {4: [1, 19.9884]}, {4: [3, 122.153]}, {5: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [3, 122.153]}, {7: [1, 19.9884]}, {8: [1, 19.9884]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}]}, 
 3:{'Neighbour_values': [{3: [2, 89.5488]}, {3: [4, 23.0558]}, {3: [6, 20.4196]}, {4: [1, 19.9884]}, {4: [2, 89.5488]}, {5: [1, 19.9884]}, {5: [4, 22.9872]}, {6: [2, 89.5488]}, {6: [4, 22.9872]}, {7: [2, 89.5488]}, {7: [4, 22.9872]}, {8: [2, 89.5488]}]}, 
 4:{'Neighbour_values': [{3: [1, 122.153]}, {3: [3, 71.1785]}, {3: [6, 20.4196]}, {4: [6, 20.4196]}, {5: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [1, 19.9884]}, {6: [3, 122.153]}, {6: [6, 20.4196]}, {7: [1, 19.9884]}, {7: [6, 19.9002]}, {8: [1, 19.9884]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}]}, 
 5:{'Neighbour_values': [{3: [4, 23.0558]}, {4: [4, 23.0362]}, {6: [3, 122.153]}, {6: [4, 22.9872]}, {7: [4, 22.9872]}, {8: [3, 122.153]}, {8: [4, 22.9872]}]}
   }

for value in range(3,9):
  for in_d in d.values():
    for in_in_d in in_d['Neighbour_values']:
      if value-1 in in_in_d:
        print(in_in_d[value-1][1])
```

Comment: Nearly what I was looking for, I'll make some improvisations using your logic. Thanks :) @bulbus

Comment: if possible, could you maybe provide a more basic way of printing, say using nested `for` loops and showing them explicitly in the code? (rather than using the `.join` and what follows). I am still not completely adept with Python

Comment: I got an error when I ran the first updated code with `Neighbour_values`: `for in_in_d in in_d['Neighbour_values']:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`. I want to keep the string `Neighbour_values` in the list

Comment: Just saw this, did it resolve? Can you run it with `d` initialised as shown?

Comment: I can run it with `d` from the second part where you omitted the `Neighbour_values`, although I want to keep that, so I ran the first code again and that's when I encountered that error

Comment: see my latest update, as I believe this is what you were intending originally.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, dictionaries do not have a specific order.
However, you CAN use `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve the order that keys were inserted.

You can use it like so:

```
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
ordered = OrderedDict(d)
```

and to get the previous key's values, you could do something like this:

```
def previous_value(dictionary, current_key):

    # Get the list of keys from the OrderedDict
    keys = list(dictionary.keys())

    # Get an index of the current key and offset it by -1
    index = keys.index(current_key) - 1

    # return the previous key's value
    return dictionary[keys[index]]
```

Testing it:

```
print('value before "three":    {}'.format(previous_value(ordered, 'three')))
# prints - value before "three":    2

print('value before "two":  {}'.format(previous_value(ordered, 'two')))
# prints - value before "two":  1
```